# Three.js - What's wrong with this blender exported object?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm exporting individual pieces from a larger model in blender, and some of the objects throw a couple errors and don't load. Here are the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transparent' of undefined
```

Here's a gist of one of the json files from blender that doesn't work: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jtmkrueger/7b46cf68975be7d27d67/raw/31be5d92c0749d55bcff61822aaec42985f20205/charger.json

The json file lints properly, and other objects from the same model load in fine. I'm not sure what's wrong with this particular one.

Here's my code to load the json:

```
  App.JsonLoader.load(mesh, function (geometry, materials) {
    var componentMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    componentMesh.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
    componentMesh.position.y = 50;
    componentMesh.position.x = 0;

    App.vehicle.object3d.add(componentMesh);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer is no longer relevant

---

Your model doesn't include a `materials` attribute, which gets passed into `MeshFaceMaterial`. The 2nd line of the error message shows that Three is looking for `transparent` in `materials`, but it's undefined.

You can either:

1. Ditch `new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)` and build your own material.
2. Include `materials` in your model.

[Here](https://github.com/tutsplus/webgl-models-animation/blob/master/assets/model.js)'s an example of a model which includes `materials`.

Comment: There's materials: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jtmkrueger/7b46cf68975be7d27d67/raw/31be5d92c0749d55bcff61822aaec42985f20205/charger.json perhaps you only saw the truncated version of the model?

Comment: @thatmiddleway: ahhh yes, I did only see the truncated. Woops. My only other ideas are 1. making sure no cross-origin badness is happening, or 2. checking what `geometry` and `materials` are in the callback.